# "Android Library Module (shared-test) Unable to Recognize Third-Party Library from App Module"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, aar

I am encountering an issue in my Android project where the "shared-test" library module is unable to recognize a third-party library used in the "app" module. Additionally, I've observed that the "build/outputs/aar" directory is missing in the "app" module. The project structure includes an "app" module and a "shared-test" library module. The goal is to have the "shared-test" module access the third-party library resources and classes from the "app" module.

**Problem:**

- The "shared-test" module is not recognizing a third-party library used in the "app" module.
- The "build/outputs/aar" directory is not present in the "app" module.

1. Verified the third-party library dependency in the "app" module's `build.gradle`.
2. Checked the configurations of the "shared-test" module to include the "app" module using `implementation project(':app')`.
3. Inspected the "app" module's `build.gradle` to ensure correct application configurations.
4. Performed a clean and rebuild of the entire project.
5. Reviewed the project structure to confirm the "app" module is recognized as an Android application.
6. Checked for inclusion of the "app" module in the "settings.gradle" file.
7. Confirmed the absence of the "build/outputs/aar" directory in the "app" module.

**Expected Outcome:**
The "shared-test" module should successfully recognize and access the third-party library resources and classes from the "app" module.
ack Overflow will provide you with assistance and insights from the community.
**Actual Outcome:**
The "shared-test" module is unable to recognize the third-party library, and the "build/outputs/aar" directory is missing in the "app" module.

**Additional Notes:**

- The third-party library is specified as a dependency in the "app" module.
- The "shared-test" module has a dependency on the "app" module using `implementation project(':app')`.

**Question:**
Why is the "shared-test" module unable to recognize the third-party library from the "app" module, and how can I address this issue? Additionally, why is the "build/outputs/aar" directory not present in the "app" module?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

---

Feel free to tailor this template based on your project's specific details. Posting this on St